# Encoding the data to JWT token with NodeJS getting error PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I tried to encode the data with the secret key using the `jsonwebtoken` package in nodejs and getting the following error:

> error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
> [image: Error while encode]

The code that I used to encode the data using the secret key and algorithm is mention below:

```js
var data = {
  sub: "1234567890",
  name: "John Doe"
};

var secretKey = "secret123";

var algorithm = { algorithm: "RS384" };

getJWTToken(data, secretKey, algorithm);

let getJWTToken = function(data, secretKey, algorithm) {
  console.log(token: jsonwebtoken.sign(data, secretKey, algorithm));  
};
```

It seems the problem is the algorithm. When I use the algorithm `HS256`, `HS384` and `HS512` it's working fine but when I used the algorithm `RS256`,`RS384` and `RS512` I am getting this error.

Can anyone help me out how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the RSA-algorithms you need to provide a private [RSA key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Key_generation) in [PEM format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail) to sign the token, and a public RSA key to verify it. You can't just pass a simple string like you do it for the HSxxx algorithms.

You can generate a public/private key pair with an [online tool](https://cryptotools.net/rsagen), or with openssl as described under that link or also down below.

And then read the key an sign the token like this (examples taken from the [documentation](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken)):

```js
// sign with RSA SHA256
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('private.key');
var token = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, privateKey, { algorithm: 'RS256' });
```

and to verify with the public key:

```js
// verify a token asymmetric
var cert = fs.readFileSync('public.pem');  // get public key
jwt.verify(token, cert, function(err, decoded) {
  console.log(decoded.foo) // bar
});
```

For ESxxx and PSxxx algorithms it's basically the same as for RSxxx algorithms.
According to [this](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/openssl-key-generation) you can generate and use the same key pair for RSxxx and Psxxx algorithms like this:

```
openssl genrsa 2048 -out rsa-2048bit-key-pair.pem
```

For ES256 the keypair is different and would be generated like this:

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name prime256v1 -noout -out ec256-key-pair.pem
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Once I integrate I will approve this answer. and I have one more doubt what about the algorithm format ES*** and PS***